# Getting Kendo Grid global index with virtual scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, odata

I would like to get the global index of a given Kendo Grid row in order to implement a multi-selection across a grid **with virtual scrolling enable**.

It's easy to get the index within the displayed rows:

```
var kendoGrid = $("#myGrid").data("kendoGrid");
var index = kendoGrid.items().index(kendoGrid.select());
```

At this point, the logic would be to use the page number / page size to determine what is the global index of the selected row.

```
//Pages are base 1
index += (kendoGrid.dataSource.page() - 1) * kendoGrid.dataSource.pageSize();
```

However, this ain't working with the Kendo grid (except for the first page) as the grid is displaying rows from page previously loaded.

Example:

You have records from 1 to 200 with a page size of 100.  When you'll scroll down to the record #100, the dataBound grid event will be triggered and you'll be able to notice the dataSource page has changed from 1 to 2.

You'll also notice some rows from page 1 are still visible and their index will be calculated as a page 2 element.

For instance, the record #96 has the index 95 as long as the grid remain on page 1.  When you'll switch to page 2, the record #96 will be displayed (as the first item).  At this point, index returned by the grid for that row will be 0.  If you apply the page number / size rule above, you'll end up with the index 100.

Is there any solution that doesn't involve a row index calculated on the server side?

**Note**
If we had a PK column, it could be possible to use it to build a list of index, but we don't always have a PK column so this isn't an option.